# Use parse server API to read from db within index.j

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

```
/ Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var api = new ParseServer({
  ...
  }
});

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
// =================================================================

             MY QUESTION IS ON THIS METHOD

// =================================================================
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-  server repo on GitHub!');
});
```

This is a snippet from the index.js in parse server example(https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example).
Is it possible to use the ParseServer instance gotten from initializing the server to access the db?

Edit:
Sorry guys, I posted this question in 2017. I can't understand what I was asking. :-(.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible but its not advisable to run it like that.

Cloud code (`main.js`) is what I suggest you use.

```
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
```